# How would I put a button in the first row of every nested group in Tabulator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

```js
[
    {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", "_children":[
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1"}, //child rows nested under billy bob
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42"},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", "_children":[
            {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16"}, //child rows nested under brendon philps
            {id:6, name:"Frank Peoney", age:"12"},
        ]},
    ]},
    {id:7, name:"Jenny Jane", age:"1"},
    {id:8, name:"Martha Tiddly", age:"42", "_children":[
        {id:9, name:"Frasier Franks", age:"125"}, //child row nested under martha tiddly
    ]},
    {id:10, name:"Bobby Green", age:"11"},
]
```

So for the above JSON, there would be a button in the rows for Mary, Margret and Frasier. Tabulator exposes `getTreeParent` and `getTreeChildren` for rows, but the formatter can only format on the current cell (that I know of) - so getting the first child and putting the button there does not appear to be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by comparing the row index of the parents to the first child's index using `formatter`. If they match, return a button.  Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zubxcwq8/